# CS50x Blur Function

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently working on the blur function in PSET4 for filter-more, and I am struggling to find the bug in my code. The blur function seems to correctly filter the middle pixel and I would assume other pixels that are not on the edges, but is incorrectly filtering those on the corners and edges. Any nudges in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    // Copy to store filtered image into
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];

    int red_total = 0, blue_total = 0, green_total = 0;

    int red_average = 0, blue_average = 0, green_average = 0;

    // Goes through each pixel [i][j]
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {

            // Loops through surrounding 3x3 grid and records the average of all of them
            for (int h = -1; h < 2; h++)
            {
                // Checks if the current row is within the image array
                if (i + h >= 0 && i + h < height)
                {
                    for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++)
                    {
                        // Checks if current column is within image array
                        if (j + k >= 0 && j + k < width)
                        {
                            red_total = red_total + image[i + h][j + k].rgbtRed;
                            blue_total = blue_total + image[i + h][j + k].rgbtBlue;
                            green_total = green_total + image[i + h][j + k].rgbtGreen;
                        }
                        else continue;
                    }
                }
                else continue;
            }

            // Averages and reassigns pixel value
            red_average = round(red_total / 9.0);
            blue_average = round(blue_total / 9.0);
            green_average = round(green_total / 9.0);

            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = blue_average;
            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = red_average;
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = green_average;

            // Resets counter variables
            red_total = green_total = blue_total = 0;
            red_average = blue_average = green_average = 0;
        }
    }

    // Makes image (original) array equal to the filtered image
    for (int x = 0; x < height; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < width; y++)
        {
            image[x][y] = temp[x][y];
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Plese make https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You need to count the number of pixels that were added to the totals, and then divide by that number, instead of always dividing by 9.0. The divisor should be 4.0 for corner pixels and 6.0 for edges.

Comment: Aside: it's poor practice to initialise variables at the start, and again at the end of the loop. Initialise them *once*, at the start of each loop. It's easier to read and less error-prone.

Comment: Aside: `else continue;` at the end of a loop body is unnecessary, and should be removed.

Comment: ...and then when you have a pixel counter make sure the division is floating point division, not integer division.